# Choosing a good math font to use with Georgia text font

Tags: fonts, unicode-math, bm, math-fonts

My questions is related to combining text and math fonts. I am a real fan of Georgia-like "dense" and "no so thin" fonts. It seems that books published by AMS use similar one.

My problem is that I cannot find a good math font to fit the text: `newtxmath` seems too thin for Georgia, it fits Times New Roman more. I have tried using `STIX Math Two`, but the `\bm` package won't work with it. Also, `mathbb, mathcal` and `mathscr` styled letters look much better in `newtxmath`.

I am searching for a solution of at least one of these problems:

- Can I somehow load the symbols I like from `newtxmath` package and make `bm` work?
- What is the font that looks good with Georgia and has good support for math symbols, proper spacing and works with other packages (most prefferable -- loadable with `unicode-math` package)?

Some examples:

**newtxmath** (good `mahtbb`, but font is too thin)
[image]

**XITS** (some symbols are awkward)
[image]

**STIX math two** (very good, but `mathbb` is strange)
[image]

MWE contains a short example of a formula and text. I am including some packages into MWE that sometimes conflict with the font-loading stuff. *I use LuaLaTeX to compile*.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt,openany]{book}
\usepackage{geometry}
\geometry{
margin=1in
}
%


\usepackage{mathtools}

\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools}

\usepackage{wasysym}
%\usepackage{newtxmath}
%\usepackage[notext,not1,notextcomp]{stix}
%\let\coloneqq\relax
%\let\Coloneqq\relax
%\let\eqqcolon\relax
\usepackage[math-style=ISO]{unicode-math}
\setmathfont{STIX Two Math}
%\setmathfont{XITS Math}

\usepackage{bm}


\usepackage{mathrsfs}

\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{polyglossia}

\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX}

\setmainfont{Georgia}

\setmainlanguage{english}

\DeclareFontFamily{U}{skulls}{}
\DeclareFontShape{U}{skulls}{m}{n}{ <-> skull }{}
\newcommand{\skull}{\text{\usefont{U}{skulls}{m}{n}\symbol{'101}}}

%

\begin{document}

If $\omega$ is a positive linear functional on a $C^{\ast}$-algebra~$A$,
then we can construct a unique (up to unitary equivalence)
representation~$\pi_\omega$ of algebra~$A$ in some Hilbert
space~$H_\omega$ over field of scalars $\mathbb{C}$ and
a vector~$\xi_\omega$ such that
    $$
    \omega(a)=\left(\pi_{\omega(a)}\xi_\omega,\,\xi_\omega\right).
    $$

\end{document}
```

Comment: I get no change if I uncomment bm, did you intend to have an example that showed an error with `\bm` being used?

Comment: note `\defaultfontfeatures{Ligatures=TeX}` is the default anyway, and don't specify  `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}` with luatex

Comment: @DavidCarlisle it gives me an error if i write '\bm{\omega}'

Comment: [Tex Gyre Schola Math](http://www.gust.org.pl/projects/e-foundry/tg-math) looks quite nice with Georgia as the main font.

Comment: @MichaelFreimann but your example doesn't have `\bm` and says that you get an error if you uncomment the package loading, which doesn't seem to be the case.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle yes, I have deleted this comment from the code.

Comment: @MichaelFreimann you don't need `\bm` to get a bold omega with unicode-math the stix font has bold greek built in so you can use `\symbf{\omega}`

Comment: Short answer: none of the currently available fonts has letters compatible with Georgia. STIX is based on Times New Roman, so if `newtxmath` isn't good, neither is STIX.

Comment: @egreg what font is used in AMS books? It looks similar to Georgia.

Comment: I think they use Computer Modern. Georgia is not so distinct in letter shapes from Times, but the serifs are surely very different.

Comment: @Thruston Tex Gyre seems to be a very good choice, but it doesn't work with `\bm`. I get an error when I use it with greek symbols and get no effect using it with regular symbols.

Comment: @egreg STIX still looks better than `newtxmath` in my opinion. But can I load `mathbb` fonts from the `newtxmath` package?